# Is there any way to recognize Turkish voice on android in offline mode?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I ve searched a lot but I did not any solution. If I try to download offline languages I did not see the Turkish language, And I try the Turkish words on it , it gives me back in English.

is there any way to do it in offline mode?

### Windows Cognitive Services for speech recognition is work offline mode?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think that's possible with Google's voice recognition services at this point.

You can see the list of languages that support offline voice recognition by navigating to:

`Settings -> Language & Input -> Google voice typing -> Offline speech recognition`.

Unfortunately Turkish (nor my native tongue Bulgarian) is supported there. On a side note though - offline dictionary is supported via Google Translate, so you can use that for offline translations.

Comment: So we can t use offline voice recognation for our languages? is there any other api for offline voice recognatiob?

Comment: None that I've heard of :( The big players in this field are obviously Google, Apple and Microsoft. Microsoft had similar offline speech recognition for Windows Phone, but that's not available as open cross-platform API (and I'm not sure which languages were supported). My hope is that Google will expand the list of supported languages. A good sign of that is the [EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE) that was added recently - there'll be more and more support for offline speech recognition.

Comment: what is EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE ?  is it support Turkish? How can I see which languages in that ?

Comment: The mentioned extra is to be used with a [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html). As the name suggest you can use it to recognize speech in your own application. Unfortunately this service works only for the same list of languages that I mentioned in my answer, so it won't work offline for Turkish for now.

Comment: So i cant use any api or any thing to do my wish?

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://www.sestek.com/speech-recognition/

They support ASR on Android.

Answer (score 0):

### You do not achive this without internet with Google api.

You just wait Google updates.